# Сложные случаи обособления

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите хотя бы одно предложение со сложным случаем обособления членов предложения.

Comment: А какие случаи Вы считаете сложными?

Answer (score 3):

1. **Авторское решение при обособлении определения**: Чувства,  чистые и светлые, как первый снег, переполняли его душу (обособленное определение).Чувства чистые и светлые, как первый снег, переполняли его душу (определение не обособляется, на него падает логическое ударение, нет паузы).
2. **Сказуемое или обособленное определение:** Море у его ног лежало безмолвное и белое от облачного дыма. Море, безмолвное и белое от облачного дыма, лежало у его ног.  Здесь перестановка слов изменяет синтаксис предложения.

Comment: Интересно, а кто назвал эти случаи "сложными"? И почему именно эти? Это общепринятый термин или самодеятельность?

Comment: Это, наверное, не сложные, а трудные случаи, то есть примеры парных вариантов, которые могут вызвать затруднение при решении.  Но, возможно, автор вопроса что-нибудь другое имел в виду.